# All unique permutations of an array of 1s and 0s

Tags: c#, arrays, permutation

i would like all unique permutations of an array for example:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

i have a code that kind of works, i'll past it below, the thing is it swaps 0s between each other and 1s between each other, and i would like to skip these permutations as they are not relevant. I thought i would need only combinations but then again an array of just {1,0} would return itself but [0,1] is also relevant to me.

EDIT: by skip i mean best to do it as soon as possible, before its even generated to save some time because the array is large and it takes a while already.

Code:

```
static IEnumerable<int[]> GeneratePermutations(int[] arr)
    {
        int n = arr.Length;
        int[] indexes = new int[n];
        int[] currentPermutation = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            indexes[i] = i;
            currentPermutation[i] = arr[i];
        }

        yield return currentPermutation;

        while (NextPermutation(indexes))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                currentPermutation[i] = arr[indexes[i]];
            }
            yield return currentPermutation;
        }
    }

    static bool NextPermutation(int[] indexes)
    {
        int n = indexes.Length;
        int i = n - 2;

        while (i >= 0 && indexes[i] >= indexes[i + 1])
        {
            i--;
        }

        if (i == -1)
        {
            return false; // All permutations generated.
        }

        int j = n - 1;
        while (indexes[i] >= indexes[j])
        {
            j--;
        }

        Swap(ref indexes[i], ref indexes[j]);

        int left = i + 1;
        int right = n - 1;
        while (left < right)
        {
            Swap(ref indexes[left], ref indexes[right]);
            left++;
            right--;
        }

        return true;
    }

    static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
    {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
```

It is not necessary to adapt current code, i am open to new solutions or something to read at that will point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question if the requirements are to "leave out combinations that are irrelevant to me". You would have to say how to know if a combination is relevant to you or not.

Comment: so lets say with an array of [1,1,0,0] it will return itself and all permutations twice for example because it swaps 0s between each other and 1s between each other, as i mentioned that scenario is not relevant because its a duplicate.

Comment: Other than that, imagine an array of length 3. You can have permutation { 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111}  - in binary those are the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7. So an array of length 3 has 8 possible permutations and they are just the numbers 0-7. To solve this permutation problem, you can  simply generate the numbers from 0 to 2^n-1, where n is the length of your array.

Comment: i see what you mean, i have tried that at first but the thing is, i need it to be 0s and 1s because i use it for identification of colors, and for example if 6 and 7 in your example would be both green, its not relevant for me to swap them. That is why i need it that way unfortunately, unless i missunderstood your explenation.

Comment: Thats why the array is as i showed in the example, 1s are red for example and 0s are green, and if you swap last two places, the output doesnt change because it essentialy is a duplicate

Comment: By returning the same array over and over again, you may end up with identical answers. Create a new one for each answer

Comment: Are you looking for *unique* permutations, skipping duplicates?

Comment: @topsail yes { Blue, Red, Green } is not the same as { Blue, Green, Red } is indeed true, but {1,0,0} and {1,0,0} is the same, yet they are both valid permutations because of indexing. If you dont understand it after this i cant explain it any better and i apologize

HansKeﬆing yes i was looking for uniqui permutations but not skipping of already generated duplicates, since its a large array i wanned to not generate the duplicates instead. Found a solution and posted it, i ll accept it as answer when i can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest algorithm to computer all permutations of a binary number with same hamming weight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755687/what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-computer-all-permutations-of-a-binary-number-wi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have indeed found a solution that worked and generates only unique permutations:

```
    static IEnumerable<int[]> GenerateUniquePermutations(int[] array)
    {
        // Sort the array to group identical permutations together
        Array.Sort(array);

        while (true)
        {
            int[] uniquePermutation = (int[])array.Clone();
            yield return uniquePermutation;

            // Find the next lexicographically greater permutation
            int i = array.Length - 2;
            while (i >= 0 && array[i] >= array[i + 1])
            {
                i--;
            }

            if (i < 0)
            {
                // All permutations generated
                break;
            }

            int j = array.Length - 1;
            while (array[j] <= array[i])
            {
                j--;
            }

            // Swap elements at i and j
            Swap(array, i, j);

            // Reverse the elements after i
            Reverse(array, i + 1, array.Length - 1);
        }
    }

    static void Swap(int[] array, int i, int j)
    {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    static void Reverse(int[] array, int start, int end)
    {
        while (start < end)
        {
            Swap(array, start, end);
            start++;
            end--;
        }
    }
```